# How to download video with blob url?

Tags: download

I am trying to download video with src url `blob:https%3A//www.youtube.com/23aea5c8-9ae2-40dc-9417-e675ea99b386`.

Is there a process that can be followed to download all this type of videos?

Comment: If you want to download youtube videos use extenstions like Video Downloadhelper (Firefox)

Comment: i want to download from vimeo url.

Comment: Vinesh, try navigating to vimeo website and start playing the video you require to download. Video DownloadHelper will detect it and give you an option to download it. I tried it.

Comment: No Luck. when I started playing video, I saw multiple video suggestion from the extension you mentioned each of around 2 MB. when I downloaded a part, I was not able to play that small file. I was getting error that file is corrupt.

Comment: put the link in comments

Comment: it is not publicly available(login with paid service). :(
Btw, youtube videos were working fine with your suggestion. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: try http://savevideo.me/

Comment: Below I wrote some simple steps for doing it, let me know if they work for your case

Comment: [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-vimeo-videos-pre/phpaiffimemgakmakpcehgbophkbllkf) works for me

Comment: With Chrome 60.0.3112.113 I was able to directly open a video url with blob in the beginning and then simply saving it.

Comment: Can you provide a public link to test the solutions? I never had a problem downloading videos from vimeo or youtube with [Jdownloader 2](http://jdownloader.org/jdownloader2). It even lets you choose quality of video.

Comment: In the general case it's necessary to understand [what blob URL is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used). Then it's possible to intercept calls to blob URL creation and obtain the source data. --

Comment: If you would like to batch download youtube videos (Like playlists) I recommend [this](https://youtubemultidownloader.net/playlists.html). It allows you to download batch youtube videos with minimal ads. If you need to download copyrighted content, just turn `youtube.com` into `youtubepp.com`. It will redirect.

Comment: The easiest way I found was to use https://www.downloadhelper.net/ Browser Extension.

Comment: The most common workaround I've seen posted in other places is to open your browser's devtools and check the network tab for a playlist being downloaded (often m3u8, but I've also seen mpd). That playlist is often where the data for blob is actually coming from. Open that playlist in VLC and instead of playing it, convert it to some other local container, the first option, mp4, seems to work most of the time

Comment: Here's a solution nobody here has suggested yet.  Always works on all kinds of videos, even types that haven't been invented yet.  Simpler than all the other methods suggested.  Also allows you to crop the video and cut off the start or end, any offset.  Simply get your screen capture program, available on most OSes, and probably it can capture videos off the screen.  Capture the video as you play it.

Answer (score 103):

I found a way to download the video with `blob url` in `Vimeo` (reading [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/HowToHack/comments/41mvtc/how_to_join_vimeo_video_segments/) i understood how doing it). I write the simple steps here.
I'm using Google Chrome:

1. Open the `More Tools` → `Developer Tools`
2. Check if in the video tag there is something like this:

   ```
   <video preload="" src="blob:https://player.vimeo.com/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"></video>
   ```
3. Copy the src of the iframe tag, if any, something like `http://player.vimeo.com/video/XYZ` if you found it you can go straight to the point 7, otherwise follow steps 4, 5, 6.
4. Now look for this string `https://skyfire.vimeocdn.com/.../master.json?base64_init=1` inside the page (using the Developer View), you should found it inside a javascript function, like this:

   ```
   (function(e,a){var t={"cdn_url":"https://f.vimeocdn.com","view":1,"request":{"files":{"dash":{"origin":"gcs","url":"https://48skyfiregce-a.akamaihd.net/.../master.json?base64_init=1","cdn":"
   ```
5. Copy the link inside the url field on a new Chrome tab, for example `https://48skyfiregce-a.akamaihd.net/.../master.json?base64_init=1` end open it with a browser, it will open you a json file like this:

   ```
   {
       "clip_id": XYZ,
       "base_url": "../",
       "video": [
                    { ... ... ...
   ```
6. Now compose a url with your id `XYZ` like this: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/XYZ`
7. Replace `blob:https://player.vimeo.com/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` inside the video tag with that last url (the one created in the previous step #6).
8. Now you will notice that magically the src field inside of the video tag changed (if it does not, try step 7 multiple times)...

   ```
   <video preload="none" src="https://fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/XX/XXX/X/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX.mp4?token=abcdefg"></video>
   ```
9. Use that new link to dowload it directly, it's something like this:

   https://fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/XX/XXX/X/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX.mp4?token=abcdefg

Comment: Impressive. How have you figured this out?

Comment: In step 7, what do you mean with "that last url inside the html"?

Comment: nope... didn't magically change. Ideas?

Comment: there are sites that you just copy paste the URL and it will download it..

Comment: Works perfectly, but the trick is sometimes you have to replace the "src" value multiple times to get the download link generated.

Comment: Thank you @Ashrith I'll add your trick as an answer improvement

Comment: Can you explain the "Last URL inside the HTML" bit ?

Comment: It's the URL composed in the step #6

Comment: @daria this doesn't work for Vimeo. blob URL's from Vimeo are streamed as XHR requests every second or so. There is no request URL available in the Network tab.

Comment: You can get the clip id directly from video downloader chrome extension :)

Comment: Currently, for Vimeo it is much easier and doesn't require all the steps. Simply open a Vimeo video, find the `<video>` tag in the dev tools DOM structure and change the `src` attribute from `blob:...` to `x`. Nothing will happen - this is ok. Now change it again, to `y`. Chrome will convert it 'magically' to the URL like in step 8 or 9. :-)

Comment: Also work in Firefox/firebug, but as @Ashrith said, I needed to paste the url twice. Awesome trick!!

Comment: @StanE it works like a charm, in Firefox too, and is definitely faster...

Comment: @StanE Wow! How does that work?

Comment: Genius! My process was a bit bumpy but eventually did work! Love it!

Comment: @StanE I don't know how you have found it, but it works like a charm! Nota Bene: the "x" and "y" he mentions are literally the exact values you can enter, they don't represent anything else.

Comment: @StanE, this applies for  all video sites or only for youtube?

Comment: @Zhang Vimeo, not YouTube. I tried it on several other sites, but it doesn't seem to work anywhere else, afaik. Maybe it's something with JavaScript on Vimeo, which triggers this.

Comment: It is work for `https://iq.com/` website?

Comment: I don't think that it could work with that iq.com, sorry

Comment: @StanE just confirming for the masses that your approach still works in Jan 2021, and it's WAY easier than everything else.

Comment: Hello @madx I'm trying to follow the steps. Can you tell me how to replace jove.com/03cf88b7-86a3-402a-9e1b-9d40a52f7b81 inside the video tag please?

Comment: Sorry @GennaroArguzzi your link is broken again

Comment: Hi @madx the original link is this one (I tried it in chrome and firefox and it works): https://app.jove.com/it/v/10405/hydraulic-jumps#:%7E:text=A%20hydraulic%20jump%20is%20a,decreased%20average%20flow%20velocity%20downstream.

Comment: You could try with this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-downloadhelper/lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk I just tried with it and worked fine

Comment: @madx I tried to click on it while I was watching the video and it says "no media to process in the current page"..how did you do it?

Comment: Have you installed the Video DownloadHelper Companion too? From this link: "https://www.downloadhelper.net/install-coapp" --> Other system installers, you can download it and install the companion. Then restart Chrome, as soon as you start the video it should appear the possibility to download it.

Comment: Hi @madx sorry for the delay. I tried and the result is the same (actually the first time I saw the video, but when I clicked to download it, an error occured).

Comment: Ok, I don't know. For me it works fine even with that extension.
But I have found another solution. Install this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fetchvvideo-downloaderhls/imleiiaoeclikefimmcdkjabjbpcdgaj/related
Then look at the m3u8 URL that appears in the extension and copy paste it in the browser to download it. I checked the video with VLC after the download.

Comment: @madx thank you very very much for your precious help and for your willingness!!! It works very well:)

Comment: Hi @madx if possible I'd like to ask you a question: do you know how to download this video? FetchV video downloader fails in this case. Sorry for the nuisance https://video.repubblica.it/salute/medicina-e-ricerca/aspartame-e-questione-di-dose-cosa-sappiamo-del-rischio-tumori/448635/449601?ref=RHRT-BG-P1-S1-T1&rpl=1

Comment: For that page you can try this chrome extension "Stream Recorder - download HLS as MP4": https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stream-recorder-download/iogidnfllpdhagebkblkgbfijkbkjdmm/related

Comment: @madx thank you a lot! Wonderful extension.

Answer (score 42):

```
<video src="blob:https://www.example.tv/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx">
  <source src="https://cdn.example.tv/api/media/tv/xyzxyz/index" type="application/x-mpegurl">
</video>
```

I also had `blob:` URL in `video/@src`, but by watching `Developer tools` > `Network` during playback it turned out that `video/source/@src` was URL for `m3u8` playlist.

An `m3u8`-backed video can be readily downloaded by either:

- `ffplay -i "https://cdn.example.tv/api/media/tv/xyzxyz/1080/index.m3u8"`
- `ffmpeg -i "https://cdn.example.tv/api/media/tv/xyzxyz/1080/index.m3u8" -codec copy file.mkv`

---

*tl;dr - blob URL sounds like the binary you want to get but there might be easier way to get the video. Just check out Network tab in Dev tools while you play the video to see what you are actually fetching.*

Comment: Works on my machine! And you can supply multiple kinds of stream inputs with `-i <URL> -i <URL> -i <URL>` to merge video, audio, and subtitles all into one output :)

Comment: @mcandre Yes, that's a good tip. You can also possibly find `m3u8` *metalist* (i.e. m3u8 file referring other m3u8 files) and ffmpeg will download and merge it properly, so you don't need to manually specify multiple inputs `-i`.

Comment: Confirmed that this still works!

Comment: The key is they can send the m3u8 payload in an obscure way, but it is usually AFTER the video player JS and BEFORE the chunks, so it will narrow down the files you need to dig through.

Comment: I always used to check Network Tab but got sidelined this time by looking at the HTML source. Dev Tools rock! Thank you so much for reminding its importance

Answer (score 12):

This answer is for Twitter URLs -

1. Right click on the video and click Inspect Elements -

You'll find a code like this

```
<div id="playerContainer" class="player-container full-screen-enabled" data-config="{&quot;is_360&quot;:false,&quot;duration&quot;:28617,&quot;scribe_widget_origin&quot;:true,&quot;heartbeatEnabled&quot;:true,&quot;video_url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/844504104512749568\/pu\/pl\/e91Du5N2TZ09ZaW_.m3u8&quot;,&quot;disable_embed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;videoInfo&quot;:{&quot;title&quot;:null,&quot;description&quot;:null,&quot;publisher&quot;:{&quot;screen_name&quot;:&quot;MountainButorac&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Mountain Butorac&quot;,&quot;profile_image_url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/808318456701521920\/vBvlAASx_normal.jpg&quot;}},&quot;cardUrl&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/t.co\/SdSorop3uN&quot;,&quot;content_type&quot;:&quot;application\/x-mpegURL&quot;,&quot;owner_id&quot;:&quot;14120461&quot;,&quot;looping_enabled&quot;:true,&quot;show_cookie_override_en&quot;:true,&quot;visit_cta_url&quot;:null,&quot;scribe_playlist_url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/twitter.com\/MountainButorac\/status\/844505243538931714\/video\/1&quot;,&quot;source_type&quot;:&quot;consumer&quot;,&quot;image_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/844504104512749568\/pu\/img\/FFt3qkbeOh0RlGfZ.jpg&quot;,&quot;heartbeatIntervalInMs&quot;:5000.0,&quot;use_tfw_live_heartbeat_event_category&quot;:true,&quot;video_loading_timeout&quot;:45000.0,&quot;status&quot;:{&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;Wed Mar 22 11:05:14 +0000 2017&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:844505243538931714,&quot;id_str&quot;:&quot;844505243538931714&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Took my Goddaughter to meet the pope. She stole his hat! https:\/\/t.co\/SdSorop3uN&quot;,&quot;truncated&quot;:false,&quot;entities&quot;:{&quot;hashtags&quot;:[],&quot;symbols&quot;:[],&quot;user_mentions&quot;:[],&quot;urls&quot;:[],&quot;media&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:844504104512749568,&quot;id_str&quot;:&quot;844504104512749568&quot;,&quot;indices&quot;:[57,80],&quot;media_url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/844504104512749568\/pu\/img\/FFt3qkbeOh0RlGfZ.jpg&quot;,&quot;media_url_https&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/844504104512749568\/pu\/img\/FFt3qkbeOh0RlGfZ.jpg&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/t.co\/SdSorop3uN&quot;,&quot;display_url&quot;:&quot;pic.twitter.com\/SdSorop3uN&quot;,&quot;expanded_url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/twitter.com\/MountainButorac\/status\/844505243538931714\/video\/1&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;photo&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:{&quot;small&quot;:{&quot;w&quot;:340,&quot;h&quot;:604,&quot;resize&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;},&quot;thumb&quot;:{&quot;w&quot;:150,&quot;h&quot;:150,&quot;resize&quot;:&quot;crop&quot;},&quot;large&quot;:{&quot;w&quot;:576,&quot;h&quot;:1024,&quot;resize&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;},&quot;medium&quot;:{&quot;w&quot;:576,&quot;h&quot;:1024,&quot;resize&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;}}}]},&quot;source&quot;:&quot;\u003ca href=\&quot;http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\&quot; rel=\&quot;nofollow\&quot;\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e&quot;,&quot;in_reply_to_status_id&quot;:null,&quot;in_reply_to_status_id_str&quot;:null,&quot;in_reply_to_user_id&quot;:null,&quot;in_reply_to_user_id_str&quot;:null,&quot;in_reply_to_screen_name&quot;:null,&quot;geo&quot;:null,&quot;coordinates&quot;:null,&quot;place&quot;:null,&quot;contributors&quot;:null,&quot;retweet_count&quot;:0,&quot;favorite_count&quot;:0,&quot;favorited&quot;:false,&quot;retweeted&quot;:false,&quot;possibly_sensitive&quot;:false,&quot;lang&quot;:&quot;en&quot;},&quot;show_cookie_override_all&quot;:true,&quot;video_session_enabled&quot;:false,&quot;media_id&quot;:&quot;844504104512749568&quot;,&quot;view_counts&quot;:null,&quot;statusTimestamp&quot;:{&quot;local&quot;:&quot;4:05 AM - 22 Mar 2017&quot;},&quot;media_type&quot;:1,&quot;user&quot;:{&quot;screen_name&quot;:&quot;MountainButorac&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Mountain Butorac&quot;,&quot;profile_image_url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/808318456701521920\/vBvlAASx_bigger.jpg&quot;},&quot;watch_now_cta_url&quot;:null,&quot;tweet_id&quot;:&quot;844505243538931714&quot;}" data-source-type="consumer">
```

2.Copy Paste above code in notepad++. Replace all the **`&quot;`** with **`"`** and `\/` wth **`/`** in notepad++. (Use CTRL+H)

You'll get something like

```
{
    "is_360": false,
    "duration": 28617,
    "scribe_widget_origin": true,
    "heartbeatEnabled": true,
    "video_url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/844504104512749568/pu/pl/e91Du5N2TZ09ZaW_.m3u8",

    "disable_embed": "0",
    "videoInfo": {
        "title": null,
        "description": null,
        "publisher": {
            "screen_name": "MountainButorac",
            "name": "Mountain Butorac",
            "profile_image_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/808318456701521920/vBvlAASx_normal.jpg"
        }
    },
    "cardUrl": "https://t.co/SdSorop3uN",
    "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL",
    "owner_id": "14120461",
    "looping_enabled": true,
    "show_cookie_override_en": true,
    "visit_cta_url": null,
    "scribe_playlist_url": "https://twitter.com/MountainButorac/status/844505243538931714/video/1",
    "source_type": "consumer",
    "image_src": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/844504104512749568/pu/img/FFt3qkbeOh0RlGfZ.jpg",
    "heartbeatIntervalInMs": 5000.0,
    "use_tfw_live_heartbeat_event_category": true,
    "video_loading_timeout": 45000.0,
    "status": {
        "created_at": "Wed Mar 22 11:05:14 +0000 2017",
        "id": 844505243538931714,
        "id_str": "844505243538931714",
        "text": "Took my Goddaughter to meet the pope. She stole his hat! https://t.co/SdSorop3uN",
        "truncated": false,
        "entities": {
            "hashtags": [],
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [],
            "urls": [],
            "media": [{
                "id": 844504104512749568,
                "id_str": "844504104512749568",
                "indices": [57, 80],
                "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/844504104512749568/pu/img/FFt3qkbeOh0RlGfZ.jpg",
                "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/844504104512749568/pu/img/FFt3qkbeOh0RlGfZ.jpg",
                "url": "https://t.co/SdSorop3uN",
                "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/SdSorop3uN",
                "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/MountainButorac/status/844505243538931714/video/1",
                "type": "photo",
                "sizes": {
                    "small": {
                        "w": 340,
                        "h": 604,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "thumb": {
                        "w": 150,
                        "h": 150,
                        "resize": "crop"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "w": 576,
                        "h": 1024,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "w": 576,
                        "h": 1024,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        "source": "\u003ca href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c/a\u003e",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "geo": null,
        "coordinates": null,
        "place": null,
        "contributors": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "favorited": false,
        "retweeted": false,
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "lang": "en"
    },
    "show_cookie_override_all": true,
    "video_session_enabled": false,
    "media_id": "844504104512749568",
    "view_counts": null,
    "statusTimestamp": {
        "local": "4:05 AM - 22 Mar 2017"
    },
    "media_type": 1,
    "user": {
        "screen_name": "MountainButorac",
        "name": "Mountain Butorac",
        "profile_image_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/808318456701521920/vBvlAASx_bigger.jpg"
    },
    "watch_now_cta_url": null,
    "tweet_id": "844505243538931714"
}
```

From above JSON format, see the value **video_url**

```
https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/844504104512749568/pu/pl/e91Du5N2TZ09ZaW_.m3u8
```

*The issue here is, after August 1st, 2016, Twitter is no longer using .mp4 videos, but converting to a new HLS, adaptive-streaming format, with a **.m3u8** file extension.*

> .m3u8 files are basically just a text file wrapper, they are super
>   small (300-500 bytes), and when you open them with a text editor, they
>   contain links to different video sizes

3. Open the file m3u8 in notepad++, it would contain code like this

> EXTM3U EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
>   EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=256000,RESOLUTION=180x320,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.42001f"
>   **/ext_tw_video/844504104512749568/pu/pl/180x320/_Z42SY5zwMlLdFYx.m3u8** 
>   EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=832000,RESOLUTION=360x640,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.42001f"
>   **/ext_tw_video/844504104512749568/pu/pl/360x640/-Phfjbbx2yinirLi.m3u8**

4. Copy the respective link from above as per your resolution need. Repeat the same step until you have **.ts** file. Download the **.ts** file (the video file).

Comment: What do you mean, "you'll get something like" -- from where?

Comment: @User from the code above it which starts like `<div id="playerContainer"`

Comment: Hey, in step 4, what do you mean by "copy the respective link" ? It isn't a valid URL, and I can't find how to get the video with it. EDIT : OK, right, I found it. You should mention that you have to put "https://video.twimg.com" before it and access the URL.

Comment: If you can't find the `id="playerContainer"` element look for `og:video:url` and open the url in the content, and inspect the source of that.

Comment: Another way to do it on **twitter** is to run `document.querySelector('video').src` in your browser developer tools console tab.

Comment: There is currently no `playerContainer` anymore, so, this answer is no more usable.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me using Chrome, but I would think any browser that has "Developer Tools" would work.  I hope this helps all of humanity...

Go to the web page with the embedded video.  Open up Developer Tools (for Chrome it's **Right-Click** | **Inspect**.  For Firefox it's **Right-Click** | **Inspect Element**.

On the top of the Inspector, there will be a bunch of tabs.  Select the **Network** tab.  Look for the **Headers** tab.  If the video auto-starts, you may have to stop it.  Also click the **Record** (red circle icon far left under the **Network** tab.  You'll want to stop recording.

When the page has completely loaded, click the **Record** button, and on the video, click **Play**.  You'll see a bunch of requests/responses show up in the **Headers** area.  You're looking for a request with the playlist (**.m3u8**) for the video.  The URL should look something like this in the **Headers** section

https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/1289861/sp/0/playManifest/entryId/1_zb2s80ga/format/applehttp/protocol/https/a.m3u8

Copy/paste that link into your browser, and at least in Chrome, that file (**a.m3u8**) will be downloaded.  The filename for your site may differ.

Go to where you saved that file and open it with **VLC**.  Select **Media** | **Convert / Save**.  Click the **Add...** button and find the .m3u8 file you just downloaded.  Click **Open**.  Click on the **Convert / Save** button.  Make sure **Convert** is selected, and click **Browse** to set the destination of the converted file.

Click the **Automatically select filename extension (.mp4)** in the bottom left of the window, and click **Save**.  Select **Start** and you should see the video play, and once that's done, the MP4 video should be in your save location.

Good luck.

Comment: “Select Media…”—from where?

Answer (score 2):

This is for blob video from **facebook**.  Requires minimum technical expertise.

1. On the video, click on the **three dots in the upper right** and click **'Copy Link'**.  Link will look like this:  https://fb.watch/1F3iBykxNf/
2. Open URL in browser.
3. Now you have the ablility to right-click the video hitbox.  **Right-click the video hitbox**, and click **'Copy video URL at current time'**.  The URL will look something like this:  https://www.facebook.com/686268088027568/videos/784217565526864/?t=0
4. Paste that URL into https://fbdown.net/.  For me I was able to get an mp4 video.

I have no affiliation with fbdown.net.

Comment: The site is down.

Comment: Accepted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843356/decoding-facebooks-blob-video-url does the job.

Comment: https://fdown.net/index.php works for me, https://fbdown.net/ doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

A blob is already an indicator that content has already been downloaded, so there's no need to download again. As opposed to text data, a blob is binary data and therefore is much smaller (each char takes two bytes in JavaScript) than text or text encoded data. Another benefit of blob is since data has been already downloaded, the browser doesn't need to send multiple requests to the originating server to render the same content.

Instead, the server packages content and any instructions for further content to be added (at client side), sends to browser (client) which renders content & handles any content update on client side, relieving server from additional traffic or workload. Blobs have their roots in databases, which evolved to store data as binary objects, for the very same reasons of efficiency. The beginnings of blobs were already evident in the days when dynamic webpages were making headlines and client side scripting became a thing.

A blob itself is data/resource, as opposed to a URL which points to source of data, and can be as simple as an array of bytes or a single file. To extract data from a blob for rendering in a browser, pass the blob to `URL.createObjectURL()` to create a blob URL in the browser, of the form 
`blob:[protocol]://[server].[domain]/[blob ID]` 

eg. `blob:https://thenewsit.com/345a291c-ac2e-456a-a202-2a8f131327ea`

This URL then becomes the source of data eg. fed to `src` attribute of html tags or elements for rendering in the browser, without involving the server. In your case, you already have a blob url, meaning the video data is already in the browser and the browser is showing you the video contained in that blob object, instead of getting it from the server (youtube).

An example to create a blob & render content from blob object:

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="fileItem" onchange="onChange()">
 <video></video>
 <br><label id="blob"></label>
```

JavaScript

```
function onChange() {
  var file = document.getElementById('fileItem').files[0];
  var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  document.getElementById('blob').innerHTML = "Blob URL is:<br>".concat(url); 
  document.getElementById('fileItem').type = "hidden";

  vid.src = url;
  vid.load();
  vid.onloadeddata = function() {
    vid.play();
  }
}
```

Tested in `jsfiddle`

Comment: This is all great but given an arbitrary blob URL (that's not under your control because you extracted it from some <video> element from the DOM) how do you store the video in a location of your choice? For instance, on the website where the blob URL was valid I tried to add a second <video> element, with `src="<blob url>"`, to the page using the dev tools but this didn't work.

Comment: This is all good and well but given an arbitrary blob URL (that's not under your control because you extracted it from some <video> element from the DOM) how do you store the video in a location of your choice? For instance, on the page from which I extracted the blob URL I used the dev tools to add a second <video> element, with src="<blob url>", and then used `$0.play()` on the console (where `$0` is the custom video element I had created & selected in the inspector), but this didn't work. "The element has no supported sources."

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to download a video with `blob url` in `Vimeo` (see the [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1130616/355601) in this page).

> **This solution is suitable only if you want just the video without the
>   sounds!**

So, if you want to download **just a Vimeo video** (often without sounds), I can confirm that this Google Chrome extension works really good: [Flash Video Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flash-video-downloader/aiimdkdngfcipjohbjenkahhlhccpdbc).

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers are nice hacks, but simplest way is to use https://jdownloader.org/, and paste `m3u8` playlist link into it.

Comment: How would one get an M3U8 playlist link from a blob URL?

Comment: @2540625 I don't know how JDownloader parses, ask developers

Answer (score 0):

For Instagram stories/videos have a look at the network tab of the Dev Tools. There, while the video is playing/being loaded, you should see one or several network requests (JS fetch requests) to an .mp4 file

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/<filename>.mp4?<lots of parameters here>&bytestart=XXXXX&byteend=YYYYYY
```

Copy this URL, change bytestart to 0 and byteend to the maximum value you see in your network requests (once the video has fully loaded/played), then paste this modified URL into a new tab. -> You should see a standalone video. Now do right click -> Save.