# How to download video with blob url from Dailymotion?

Tags: video

I am trying to download video with src url blob:http://www.dailymotion.com/8992e42d-2889-4f48-939b-0439126ab96c

from this webpage
http://www.online.dramacafe.in/%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A9-5-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%A9-hd-720p-game-of-thrones-season-1-%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84-video_7ce4005ff.html

Is there a process that can be followed to download all this type of videos?

Comment: Generally a duplicate of [How to download video with blob url? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1033563/how-to-download-video-with-blob-url)

Answer (score 1):

[VideoLAN VLC](https://www.videolan.org/index.html) can *stream* to disk anything that can be displayed.
*Caveats:*

- You're limited to the screen resolution.
- Depending on CPU and graphics power, capture may appear jerky.
- It may take a bit of playing with parameters to get an acceptable result.

[image]

VLC is available for almost any platform, including Android, Linux, Mac and Windows.

Comment: Or better yet: Network -> Enter the URL -> Play/Stream -> Record. Spares you the whole hassle.