# Downloading blob videos

Tags: video, download

I have been trying to get a couple of videos from ysl.com for a personal project. Unfortunately standard video downloaders don't have much success on the formats the site uses.

One example link here: https://www.ysl.com/ch/shop-product/unisex/fw14campaign_section

In the second video from the link, I was able to find blob:https://www.ysl.com/6dd723d0-4c79-40d3-a828-a86d22736b51

However, I don't know what I could do from there; I've tried various extensions and playing around with sources but never found success.

If anyone has any advice I would appreciate it very much—I am not trying to pirate or do illegal things, I just find the videos don't always load correctly so downloading them would be preferable.

Thank you.

Comment: [Jdownloader 2](http://jdownloader.org/jdownloader2) shows 120 videos (362 MB) when you tell it to "analyse and add links" after copying the link to clipboard. Are those the videos you need?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm hoping to download all the videos in the "campaign" section. Sorry, I'm not familiar with Jdownloader.

Comment: You said "if anyone has any advice". Mine is give it a try. When you want to download a video from a website, first let Jd2 deal with it before trying something more complicated. I don't use another download manager. It's free, updated every day, multiplataform (java) and is able to manage all kind of file-sharing servers. It lets you choose all video formats from youtube, and download its subtitles, even voice-recognition cc. For me it's a must.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download video with blob url?](https://superuser.com/questions/1033563/how-to-download-video-with-blob-url)

Comment: Maybe, but my answer is tested in the specific case of the OP, while I certainly doesn't know if it's even of value in the other question (the OP didn't provide a link to test), so I think this question-answer pair has got its own entity. The title is misleading, because the OP here doesn't want a general method to download blob videos, just a way to get these.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this method works also with another blob videos, but more pages with this kind of videos would be needed to test it. In your case, here's what you can do.

Install the extension for Chromium-based browsers [Adobe HDS / HLS Video Saver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-hds-hls-video-saver/pibndofbpkoaipoidbkephfhhnapkccn?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).

After that, open [the page](https://www.ysl.com/ch/shop-product/unisex/fw14campaign_section), click on the extension icon and then on the    <kbd>DOWNLOAD</kbd>    button.

[image]

If it shows you a forbidden sign, play a little of the video and pause it. Then you will be able to click it and the page of the extension will open. In this case, you can see two links.

[image]

If you click on any of them, a drop-down list will open with several options to download.

[image]

Scrolling down, the list will show different options to download, from lower to higher resolution.

[image]

Click on the desired resolution and the chunks of the video will begin to download and will be joined by the extension. The result appears as a download named `video.ts` so you may want to give it a comprehensive name.

[image]

Comment: The link in this answer no longer works. See instead, [HDS / HLS Video Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hds-hls-video-downloader/gelfgldejnhgpjcbnfpkglhpelajafao) extension for Chromium-based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

A blob is a copy of content that has already been downloaded, so there's no need to download again. As opposed to text data, a blob is binary data and therefore is much smaller (each char takes two bytes in JavaScript) than text or text encoded data. Another benefit of blob is since data has been already downloaded, the browser doesn't need to send multiple requests to the originating server to render the same content.

Instead, the server packages content and any instructions for further content to be added (at client side), sends to browser (client) which renders content & handles any content update on client side, relieving server from additional traffic or workload. Blobs have their roots in databases, which evolved to store data as binary objects, for the very same reasons of efficiency. The beginnings of blobs were already evident in the days when dynamic webpages were making headlines and client side scripting became a thing.

A blob itself is data/resource, as opposed to a URL which points to source of data, and can be as simple as an array of bytes or a single file. To extract data from a blob for rendering in a browser, pass the blob to `URL.createObjectURL()` to create a 'blob URL' in the browser, of the form
`blob:[protocol]://[server].[domain]/[blob ID]`

eg. `blob:https://thenewsit.com/345a291c-ac2e-456a-a202-2a8f131327ea`

This URL then becomes the source of data eg. fed to `src` attribute of html tags or elements for rendering in the browser, without involving the server.

Here's an example to create a blob, extract data from it & display on browser:

HTML

```
 <input type="file" id="fileItem" onchange="onChange()">
 <video></video>
 <br><label id="blob"></label>
```

JavaScript

```
function onChange() {
  var file = document.getElementById('fileItem').files[0];
  var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  document.getElementById('blob').innerHTML = "Blob URL is:<br>".concat(url); 
  document.getElementById('fileItem').type = "hidden";

  vid.src = url;
  vid.load();
  vid.onloadeddata = function() {
    vid.play();
  }
}
```

XHR example blob:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'doby.mp4', true);
 xhr.responseType = 'blob';
 xhr.onload = function(e) {
   var blob = this.response;
   var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
   vid.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   vid.load();
   vid.onloadeddata = function() {
     vid.play();
   }
 };
 xhr.send();
```

To access blob data on newer browsers:

```
  video.srcObject = blob;
```

Tested in `jsfiddle`