# Download video with blob url

Tags: google-chrome, video, download, vlc-media-player, website

I'm not an expert of html code. I need to download a video from the webpage
https://www.telegranducato.it/2018/07/21/tg-toscana-del-21-07-2018-edizione-delle-2030-granducato-tv/

Unfortunately the video link is blob:https://www.telegranducato.com/83f401d1-5e35-4424-9296-5f49a009cf17 and do not work with standard techniques to force download from the webpage link (VLC or WMP playing through source link).

Looking around in the web, I've found the solution below but I'm not enough used to html coding to adapt it to this webpage.

[How to download video with blob url?](https://superuser.com/questions/1033563/how-to-download-video-with-blob-url/1130616#1130616?newreg=1fa3e684aec944aa8610410da26e288c)

Can anyone give me hints and comments to donwload it and, maybe, some advice to go through html code when trying to download video from webpages?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That video is a streaming one, means it's downloaded in small chunks. So, you've to capture all the links, then download all the pieces and join them in one large video.