# download video with blob url but there is not m3u8 playlist

Tags: video, download

I have a video URL (https://www.time4education.com/my/videotest.php?videoid=a7df487a87424bf3b4a6c6768fe96c78) extracted from chrome's Developer's tools.

the video address is blob file but i couldn't find any m3u8 file ( as per other stack answers)
https://stackoverflow.com/q/42901942/13126651

This URL is only accessible until I login in other words if I directly try to access this, it needs to authenticate and then view this.

Now my problem is that I want to download this video either through a python script or any other way like youtube-dl

Note:- Previous answers on stack or superuser  didn't solve my problem.( there is no m3u8 file however there stream.mpd file)
i went through this question and its solutions but this didn't help.

[How to download video with blob url?](https://superuser.com/q/1033563/1272965)